# defining Spring request scope bean

Tags: java, spring

For using spring **request scope** bean is this definition correct?

```
<bean id="shoppingCart" class="ShoppingCart" scope="request">
<!-- This requires CGLIB --> 
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

I modified this from a **session scope** bean example, and changed only the scope definition, not sure about the proxy thing

I took this example from this link, you can see the full xml:

http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-session-scoped-beans-2.html

Comment: why do you need it to be a proxy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally - yes, it's correct.

If for every request You'd retrieve the request scoped bean directly from the `BeanFactory`, then You don't need the proxy.

But You need the proxy if You're going to use the request soped bean as a depenedncy to singleton scoped bean, for example like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
}
```

See this [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other) page for more details about scoped beans.

As a side note I'd advise to use standard JDK interface-based poxies instead of CGLIB whenever possible. More about proxying with spring can be found in [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

Comment: thanks, so in my stateles web service I need a class to hold customer information variables and keep and process them just for that request, using bean factory is a good approach for this? and is what I am going to use dependent on my previous structure or I just can create and use a bean factory whenever I want in Spring? then my final xml definition will look like this? <bean id="shoppingCart" class="ShoppingCart" scope="request"> </bean>

Comment: You don't create BeanFactory in Spring - the framework does that, becaouse the ApplicationContext **is** the BeanFactory. And aby Spring managed bean can implement BeanFactoryAware or @Autowire BeanFactory or even the whole ApplicationContext, but this binds You to the Spring API, so it's better to just @Autowire the beans You need instead of @Autowering BeanFactory and then rertrieving the bean from it.